# Programmatically set RatingBar progressDrawable

Tags: android, drawable, ratingbar

I have several RatingBars, which by default show the average rating of other users. When the user enters a rating, I would like to switch the RatingBar's progressDrawable to a different style. However, when I attempt to do so with **.setProgressDrawable(...)**, the drawable stretches to fit the RatingBar, rather than repeating in a tiled mode.

I am aware of **.setProgressDrawableTiled(...)**, which does work. However it is only available in API 21 and up. Is there an alternate way of doing this which supports API 15 and up?

Comment: Did you got the answer ?